# Stop Money gem formatting an input on validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, money-rails

I am using the Money gem with a Rails app. I am rendering the input for the amount using `humanized_money`. If I enter a wrong format for the amount in the input, besides getting a validation error, the input amount changes to a valid one.

My question is, how can I reset this amount to `0` if there is a validation error on the amount input?

Comment: did you use money rails gem ?

Comment: you need to set `default: 0` in migration did you try this

Comment: I don't want to set it at database level, I need to reset it in the user input from the interface.

Comment: ok you did not get validation error right?

Comment: Please read my question a bit more careful. I would like to reset the input's value to `0` if a validation error occurs on that field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88197/discussion-between-rajarshi-das-and-andrei-horak).